# How to send https request with no certificate using JAVA URL httpsconnection

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, httpconnection

I need to retrieve contents from HTTPS url, but I always got this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
```

This is my code:

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con =  (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setHostnameVerifier(new AlwaysTrustHostnameVerifier());

class AlwaysTrustHostnameVerifier implements X509TrustManager, HostnameVerifier 
{
   @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }      
}
```

So I don't know if I can retrieve or post to https url without installing security certificate? I ever used NodeJS / PHP, all workable, just ignore the error by adding some header info, such as rejectUnauthorized to false...

Are there any workaround in Java that can allow me to send request to https without having to install security certificate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8062602) in openJDK where you may need to get the latest fix version of openJDK or move to OracleJDK.